# Jquery Datepicker onSelect does not work

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I have an element like so that is generated inside a loop via ajax call:

```
<td class="EngIssuedFinalGradingDate"></td>
<td class="EngIssuedFinalGradingDate"></td>
<td class="EngIssuedFinalGradingDate"></td>
<td class="EngIssuedFinalGradingDate"></td>
```

I am trying to apply a datepicker to these elements:

```
$(".EngIssuedFinalGradingDate").datepicker({

pickerPosition:"bottom-left",
onSelect: function(dateText, inst) { alert("Here !"); }

});
```

But the alert does not come up, also the position is not always the bottom-left either (also looking to get it position below the td)

Comment: I'm not 100% sure. `datepicker` works on an `input` or `div` element... But on a `td`... I think that's part of the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap your `datepicker` call so that it is called whenever a new `EngIssuedFinalGradingDate` is inserted, like such:

```
$('body').on('DOMNodeInserted', '.EngIssuedFinalGradingDate', function (){
    $(".EngIssuedFinalGradingDate").datepicker({

    pickerPosition:"bottom-left",
    onSelect: function(dateText, inst) { alert("Here !"); }

    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Louys Patrice Bessette said in the comments, verifying the jQueryUI source, we can find that the datepicker can only be addded to `div` and `span` as `inline` and to `input` as `connector`.

**Source**:

```
/* Attach the date picker to a jQuery selection.
 * @param  target   element - the target input field or division or span
 * @param  settings  object - the new settings to use for this date picker instance (anonymous)
 */
_attachDatepicker: function( target, settings ) {
    var nodeName, inline, inst;
    nodeName = target.nodeName.toLowerCase();
    inline = ( nodeName === "div" || nodeName === "span" );
    if ( !target.id ) {
        this.uuid += 1;
        target.id = "dp" + this.uuid;
    }
    inst = this._newInst( $( target ), inline );
    inst.settings = $.extend( {}, settings || {} );
    if ( nodeName === "input" ) {
        this._connectDatepicker( target, inst );
    } else if ( inline ) {
        this._inlineDatepicker( target, inst );
    }
}
```